# React Component to PDF printing empty page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

Hey Using **jspdf** and **html2Canvas** to print the React Component to PDF, the content is being rendered to ref current but it is not printing it in the PDF File, printing empty page always.

```
const componentRef = useRef(null);
const barcodes = ['Sample 1', "Sample 2"];
```

```
 const printBarcodes = async () => {
    const pdf = new jsPDF("l", "in", [6, 4]);

    let yOffset = 0;

    for (let i in pageCount) {
      const currentPageBarcodes = barcodes.slice(
        i * barcodesPerPage,
        (i + 1) * 18
      );

      const container = pageRef.current;
      container.innerHTML = currentPageBarcodes
        .map((barcode) => `<div>${barcode}</div>`)
        .join("");

      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));

      const canvas = await html2canvas(container, {
        scrollY: -window.scrollY + yOffset,
      });

      if (i > 0) {
        pdf.addPage();
      }

      pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", "JPEG", 0, 0, 6, 4));
      yOffset -= 4;
    }

    pdf.save("barcodes.pdf");
  };
```

```
return (
    <>
     <div style={{display: "none"}} ref={componentRef} />
     <FontAwesomeIcon
     icon={faDownload}
     style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
     onClick={printBarcodes}
     />
    </>
)
```